# Flutter Firestore query documents where field not exist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like from my collection to read only documents **where** a specific field doesn't exist, I tried with `isNull: true` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Firestore queries are based on data in its indexes. It can only return documents that *do* exist in the indexes, so it can't return documents for which a field doesn't exist.